# Creating IMage from Text in PHP - how can I make multiline?

Tags: php, image-processing, gd, freetype

I have a script that generates images from text using PHP. It's working fine except that I would like it to generate multiline text as well with differing colors. How can it be done using PHP, GD and Freetype? Below is the code I use to generate single line text images.

```
$textval = 'This is some text to be an image';
$textcolor = '666666';


$font="arial.ttf";
$size = 9;
$padding= 1;
$bgcolor= "ffffff";

$transparent = 0;
$antialias = 0;

$fontfile = $fontpath.$font;

$box= imageftbbox( $size, 0, $fontfile, $textval, array());
$boxwidth= $box[4];
$boxheight= abs($box[3]) + abs($box[5]);
$width= $boxwidth + ($padding*2) + 1;
$height= $boxheight + ($padding) + 0;
$textx= $padding;
$texty= ($boxheight - abs($box[3])) + $padding;

// create the image
$png= imagecreate($width, $height);


$color = str_replace("#","",$bgcolor);
$red = hexdec(substr($bgcolor,0,2));
$green = hexdec(substr($bgcolor,2,2));
$blue = hexdec(substr($bgcolor,4,2));
$bg = imagecolorallocate($png, $red, $green, $blue);

$color = str_replace("#","",$textcolor);
$red = hexdec(substr($textcolor,0,2));
$green = hexdec(substr($textcolor,2,2));
$blue = hexdec(substr($textcolor,4,2));
$tx = imagecolorallocate($png, $red, $green, $blue);



imagettftext( $png, $size, 0, $textx, $texty, $tx, $fontfile, $textval );

header("content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($png);
imagedestroy($png);
exit;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this function to wrap the text before it goes into your function.

```
function wrap($fontSize, $angle, $fontFace, $string, $width){

    $ret = "";

    $arr = explode(' ', $string);

    foreach ( $arr as $word ){

        $teststring = $ret.' '.$word;
        $testbox = imagettfbbox($fontSize, $angle, $fontFace, $teststring);
        if ( $testbox[2] > $width ){
            $ret.=($ret==""?"":"\n").$word;
        } else {
            $ret.=($ret==""?"":' ').$word;
        }
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

Source: http://www.php.net/imagettftext

Comment: I tried using \n but for some reason it would also print the \n as it is :(

Comment: Hi, can you help me to, how to use custom image background, i am trying to create a captcha by using this function