# Make image just fit to a text

Tags: php, gd

I'm using PHP GD and trying to draw a text and make the image size
just fit to the text.

I found this question and tried Martin Geisler's code.

[Resize image size according to size of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936642/resize-image-size-according-to-size-of-text)

It looked work fine, but when I tried other texts, some got out of the image.

Of course, I could add extra padding, but required padding depends on the text.
That's too ad-hock.

Does anyone know proper way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

```
// Martin Geisler's version using MS Gothic
header("Content-type: image/png");

$q     = 'Image example';
$font  = './msgothic.ttc';  // MS Gothic
$size  = 30;
$bbox   = imageftbbox($size, 0, $font, $q);

$width  = $bbox[2] - $bbox[6];
$height = $bbox[3] - $bbox[7];

$im    = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$green = imagecolorallocate($im, 60, 240, 60);

imagefttext($im, $size, 0, -$bbox[6], -$bbox[7], $green, $font, $q);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

http://www.betatechnology.jp/~ao/imageexample.png

Comment: Depending on the font you are using - you may need to use [`imagettfbbox`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php)? `imageftbbox` is for FreeType fonts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize image size according to size of text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936642/resize-image-size-according-to-size-of-text)

Comment: imageftbbox ends in the same result.

Comment: As written in my question, I've already read that question.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue related to the width of the text you are writing.
3 i's are smaller than 3 o's unless you are using fixed font.

Instead of trying to create an image that has the exact right proportions I would rather make it big enough and then crop out the unused space around it.

Since you create the image, you can make the border a solid color and then crop it.
See this here for an instruction on how to do the cropping:

[Crop whitespace from image in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669683/crop-whitespace-from-image-in-php)

Comment: Thank you, uncovery. I'll try it. But it seems that there's no way to get exact bounding box from PHP. I looked into the PHP GD code, and found that it called freetype's FT_Glyph_Get_CBox function. And the freetype document says this function is not for getting exact bbox. http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-glyph_management.html#FT_Glyph_Get_CBox